# Matlab freezes after calling a figure function in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, shortcut-keys, freeze, matlab

I just updated my Ubuntu from 12.04 version to 15.04 (clean update, i.e., I erased my old Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the new one). I have Matlab R2013a installed in it and it used to work really fine, but now, all of a sudden, it freezes every time I try to plot anything. For example:

```
x = linspace(0, 10, 100); y = x;
[x, y] = meshgrid(x, y);
zx = x.^2 + y;
zy = x.*y;
quiver(x, y, zx, zy)
```

It freezes in such a way that I don't have access to any function. I can't use Ctrl + Alt + F2 or Ctrl + Alt + Del. The only thing that works is Alt + SysReq + REISUB, which reboots my computer.

In order to execute Matlab I have to run the command as super user in the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab
```

If I don't use sudo, I get the following error message:

[image: Error trying to start MATLAB without using sudo.]

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: FYI: Don't start matlab with `sudo`

Comment: But if I don't use sudo, I am unable to start Matlab...

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab` and you can start it without sudo

Comment: It didn't work... I get several errors concerning Java...

Comment: Just edited my post to include the error that I get.

Comment: Then you should create [questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). The problem can be solved. Administrator rights are not needed to start the program.

Comment: If `santiago` is your username than correct the permissions via `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~` and use MATLAB without `sudo`

Comment: Still getting the same error message... I edited the post in order to include the error message, since I can't do it in a comment line...

Answer (score 0):

I also had GL issues. Matlab support team recommended I start matlab with `-softwareopengl` flag. Figures don't look as good this way, diagonal lines don't get smoothed so you see "steps", but no more crashes for me when I see figures.